# TP4056 USB-C charging module not working

Tags: arduino, battery-charging, integrated-circuit, charger, tp4056

[image]

I am having some trouble with my TP4056 USB-C module. When I first got it, I attached a Li-po battery to the battery terminals marked B+ and B- and without any load I plugged it in the socket to see if the battery would charge but no lights lit up on the module to indicate that.

After searching on google and looking up videos I realized that the module should light up even with no battery attached when plugged into a socket which made me to believe that my TP4056 module was faulty. Then I got another TP4056 module and the same thing is happening again. No lights light up when I plug it in.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Can you show us a photo of the module?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the photo of the module rather than posting the photo as a new "answer".

Comment: Are those fuses above R1 and R2? If so, can you check for continuity while power is applied?

Comment: My guess is, you are powering it from a Type-C charger or laptop Type-C port? And my guess is, it will work if powered by e.g. Type-A to Type-C cable?

Comment: OMG @Justme Thank you soooo much dude. I tried connecting it via a Type A to type c cable and its working now!!! You are correct, Before i was using a Type C to Type C cable and it wasnt working at all. I cant thank you enough. Thanks for the suggestion aswell Colin

Answer (score 1):

You bought incorrectly designed or manufactured garbage which fails to work according standards for USB devices with Type-C connector.

The charger has just been swapped from another USB connector to Type-C and no effort made to make sure it is correctly designed.

Type-C sources require that a sink has detection resistors on CC pin to detect role of the device before turning on power. If the charger has no or incorrect detection resistors, the Type-C source cannot detect that anything is plugged in and will not give power to it.

A Type-A to Type-C cable cannot remove power and is allowed to always give power to the Type-C device, so that's why it works.

You should not trust any other thing about the charger you bought either, who knows if it will overcharge your batteries and they catch fire.

Comment: You're right and that is concerning, however it did say that this module has a bms? and the battery has a bms too so hopefully that works? but you're right i can not be trusted

Comment: Who knows if it really has a BMS and what do you even mean by a BMS? And why would you have two BMS in series?

Comment: Well the battery im using comes with a bms aswell and i couldnt find any other battery without it so im stuck with having to use 2 bms in series. Is that fine albeit redundant?